# update query with functions in typo3

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

I'm trying to use the typo3 update function with the mysql CONCAT function. Can you tell me how to manage that? What I tried:

```
$updateArray = array("field" => 'CONCAT( field'.','.$toAppend.')');
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery ('table','id = '.'"'.$some_id.'"',$updateArray);
```

That does not work, because that query is executed:

```
UPDATE table
SET
pagesEdited='CONCAT( field,'value')'
WHERE
id = "id"
```

As you see, the `concat` function is escaped.

Comment: $updateArray = array("field" => "CONCAT(`field`,$toAppend)";

Comment: @Sadikhasan: no, thats no working, still escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference documentation](http://doc-typo3.ameos.com/4.1.0/classt3lib__DB.html#36a5dcb61bba235666a7a5b0fdae9929) isn't very clear about it, however, just appending `TRUE` to your parameters of the update function should disable quoting:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery ('table','id = '.'"'.$some_id.'"',$updateArray, TRUE);
```

That also means that you will have to do your own input sanitization before lauching the query, if you haven't already:

```
$toAppend = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->fullQuoteString($toAppend, "");
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try it since I did it oldschool using the `mysql_query` function. I only read the part of the documentation and it sounds reasonable to set the boolean to `true`.

Comment: @didierc Sorry that does not work (at least with TYPO3 v6.2). You'll have to use the field names as a list or array as last parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `noQuote` parameter of the `fullQuoteArray()` method of `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection` that is used by `exec_UPDATEquery()`:

```
@param boolean|array $noQuote List/array of keys NOT to quote (eg. SQL functions) - ONLY for associative arrays
```

And when you take a kloser look ath this method, you will see that a simple true does not do the trick as expected. Simply use a list of fields (comma separated list) or an array to let TYPO3 know which fields should not be escaped.

In your case it would look like this:

```
$updateArray = array(
    'field' => 'CONCAT(field,' . $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->fullQuoteString($toAppend, 'table') . ')',
);
$where = 'id = ' . $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->fullQuoteString($some_id, 'table');

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery ('table', $where, $updateArray, 'field');
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Also note that instead of `'field'`, you may use an array: `array('field', 'and_more')`, or `['field, 'and_more']`